# vSphere power on recommendations?

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi, vcenter

I have 5 hosts in a cluster. In vCenter when I power on a VM, I get a Power on recommendations popup. But i can only choose 1 host. How do I force it to turn on on a certain host?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with how DRS is managing that VM: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.resmgmt.doc/GUID-25B61435-40FA-46B6-998B-8AD059655C6F.html

You can use DRS affinity rules to control where a VM can run.